# Apache2 сервер, теряется связь при обновлении нерутовой ссылки

Tags: apache, apache2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по настройка apache2. Я настроил apache на VPS, все работает, начиная со стартовой страницы, но когда я пытаюсь обновить страницу(или запустить сразу нестартовую), то сервер не отвечает.
Промер: 111.111.111.111 - перехожу на 111.111.111.111/login
но когда обновляю 111.111.111.111/login то получаю 404
То есть передвигаться по сайту можно, но обновление страницы в произвольном месте не работает. Это можно как-то настроить?

Comment: «Сервер не отвечает» и «возвращает 404» это таки разные вещи. Покажите конфиг который вы настроили.

Comment: Сервер не отвечает - я не дословно имел ввиду)

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80> 
 ServerAdmin stalk.sdv@gmail.com
        ServerName 159.203.2.6
        ServerAlias 159.203.2.6
 DocumentRoot /var/www/aoo.ca/public_html

 
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Больше ничего дополнительно не настраивал, в папку /var/www/aoo.ca/public_html закинул все, хост включил

Comment: Конфиг лучше добавлять в основное содержание вопроса, т.к. в комментах это не читабельно. Что в логах Апача в момент когда страница открывается нормально, а затем когда отдает 404? Файл htaccess в корне сайта есть?

Comment: Нет, файла htaccess  в папке с сайтом нет, где еще что посмотреть?

Comment: В папку с логами (/var/log/apache2) не пускает Permission denied

Comment: Если у вас VPS (ваш, я так понимаю), то зайти в эту папку можно только скорее всего под рутом. Глядя на ваш сайт, складывается впечатление, что все обрабатывает  какой-нибудь условный index.php (т.к. .htaccess с условным mod_rewrit-oм там нет), и вероятно ему чего-то не хватает. Тут дальше сложно что-то сказать, т.к. надо смотреть в движок сайта, а это по всей видимости какой-то коммерческий движок... Так что я пока пасс...

Comment: Нет, сайт на реакте, без всяких пчп. Сайт сам работает хорошо, ну... как и должен. Меня только смущает что апачь работает только с одним начальным путем и накак не работает с производными. Попробуйте зайдите - кинет на страницу логина(следавательно путь изменится), потом попробуйте обновить окно браузера.

Comment: хостинг - DigitalOcaen на ubuntu 16